# Replace Properties.Settings DB connection with connectionStrings name

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on a project that takes the connection to the database via the  `Properties.Settings.Default;
so I have to set the connection string there, but it gets annoying because I already have a connection string set in the We.config file.

How to I set the `Properties.Settings` to use `DefaultConnection` connection string in the database?

```
var request = HttpContext.Current.Request;
            var settings = Properties.Settings.Default; <--- use 'DefaultConnection' connectionString

            using (var db = new Database(settings.DbType, settings.DbConnection))
            {...}
```

my connection string

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="server=localhost;Database=DB;Integrated Security=SSPI" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

THANK YOU!

Comment: You can use `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString`

Comment: @Quercus - thank you, it worked!